# Glossaries \Gls not working properly

Tags: glossaries, capitalization

As I understand from the documentation of the glossaries package, only the first letter should be capitalized by the `\Gls` command. I don't understand why this command capitalizes ALL letters in my case, see code below. The problem occurs for `\Gls` as well as for `\Glspl`.
I also tried to uncomment the `hyperref` package, but it doesn't help. All other questions I found here didn't really match my problem.

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage[urlbordercolor={1 1 1},citebordercolor={1 1 1},linkbordercolor={1 1 1},backref]{hyperref}

\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
\newglossary*{acronyms}{Acronyms}

\newglossaryentry{lmn}
{
    type=acronyms,
    name={LMN},
    description={local model network},
    first={\glsentrydesc{lmn} (\glsentrytext{lmn})},
    plural={LMNs},
    firstplural={\glsentrydesc{lmn}s (\glsentryplural{lmn})}
}

\begin{document}
    \renewcommand{\acronymfont}[1]{\textsmaller{#1}}
    \Glspl{lmn}

    \glsresetall

    \glspl{lmn}

    % What is desired
    Local model networks (LMNs)

\end{document}
```

Compiling this code on my machine (Mac OS X El Capitan, MacTex with latest updates via "Tex Live Utility") yields:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known [`glossaries`](http://www.pirbot.com/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf) issue. Refering to page 113 I quote:

> If the first thing in the link text is a command follow by a group,
>   the upper casing is performed on the first object of the group. For
>   example, if an entry has been defined as
>
> ```
> \newglossaryentry{sample}{
>   name={\emph{sample} phrase},
>   sort={sample phrase},
>   description={an example}}
> ```
>
> Then `\Gls{sample}` will set the link text to:
>
> ```
>   \emph{\MakeUppercase sample} Phrase
> ```
>
> which will appear as *Sample* phrase.

In your case `\MakeUppercase` is taking the whole description. The simplest solution is to manually define the description for the `first` and `firstplural` keys:

```
\newglossaryentry{lmn}
{
    type=acronyms,
    name={LMN},
    description={local model network},
    first={local modern network (\glsentrytext{lmn})},
    plural={LMNs},
    firstplural={local model networks (\glsentryplural{lmn})}
}
```

[image]